# Graphic Drivers

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, graphics, ubuntu-unity

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Beta on an Acer Aspire One ZG5 net book.

Card: Mobile Intel(R) 945 Express Chip-set Family card

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 last year, two days before the release of 11.10. After I installed the KDE Plasma Desktop, my graphics fell down the cliff.

My unity started putting me on 2D mode, Gnome on classic, and on KDE, I had to use X render. Months after searching for "graphics problems," I found out when I checked "Details" in my System Settings, on the list for graphics cards, it showed NONE! I tried searching for Intel drivers that work with my model, but that's like searching for gold on a sidewalk.

Even when I did find some sort of driver, I couldn't find a way to use it. The Additional drivers list would not help either.

I have three other operating systems

- Windows 7
- Linux mint
- Pinguy OS

Those ones don't have any problems with my card. I upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS beta in hope of Canonical including my card in their driver list, and again it didn't work.

I'd appreciate anyone's word on this.

**EDIT: Sorry, I didn't realize the grammar, spelling, and punctuation were sloppy until now. I corrected the question.**

Comment: I wonder why no one answers this guy's question. Some people go insane over these things, you know.

Comment: Well if no one does answer, I can start making a graphics gravestone.

Comment: why are you using the beta when the final's out?

Comment: YAHOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!!!!!!! I fiXed it
 
i fixed it by going to linux mint and checking the package manager for opengl files and i went to ubuntu to apply installation of missing files!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Oh, that looks bad...haha. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Checking in my package manager, I found that parts of openGL were not installed; this may have resulted by installing KDE or updating.**